# How to prove $y^2=y$ for every element y in this quotient ring R/I

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring with identity $1$ such that for every element $x$ in $R$ we have $x^3=x$. Let $I =2R$ and $J=3R$ be two ideals of $R$. Prove that

1. $y^2=y$ for every $y$ in $R/I$
2. if $y \in R/J$ is nilpotent, then $y = 0$ in $R/J$ (i.e. $y=\overline{x}$ for some $x$ in $J$)

First, based on $(2x)^3=2x$, we know that $6x=0$.

However, I am stuck in this question, can someone tell me how to prove this question?

Comment: For (1), consider $(x+1)^3=x+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, consider any $x$ in $R$ and you have $$x-1 = (x-1)^3 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 = -3x^2 + 4x - 1$$

Then,  $$\,0=3 x^2 - 3x= x^2 - x + 2(x^2 - x)$$ and taking class in $R/I$ you get $\overline{x} ^2 = \overline{x}$.

For the second part use that $x^3 = x$ for every $x$ in $R$ to conclude that for every $x$ in $R$ the positive powers of $x$ con only take values $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$. Take $\overline{x}$ in $R/J$ and use the previous observation like this. If, for example,  $\overline{x}^5 = \overline{0}$ in $R/J$, then $\overline{x^3} = \overline{x}^3 = \overline{0}$ and that implies $x=x^3 = 3z \in J$ for some $z$ in $R$.

Comment: Yeah,you are right! but how to prove $x\in J$ if  $(x+J)^2$ is J?

Comment: Think about it. Start from $x^2 = 3t$...

Comment: oh,got it! $x=x^3=3xt$